# How can I find the add round key and mix column codes in AES of the crypto++ library

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, aes, crypto++

I am new in C++  code, I try to open the AES code in the crypt++ library for add round key and mix column but I do not know how to access them
Any one help me please
Thanks

Comment: They're probably [in this file](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/c5/rijndael.cpp). What exactly is your problem - finding the source, or recognising those parts, or something else? If you just want the definition, can't you find a simpler reference implementation or read the algorithm description somewhere?

Comment: thanks but i need the code of encryption (sbox_add round key and mix column)

Comment: Aren't they in that file? Is it specifically the Crypto++ implemention you want, and is it a generic portable C implementation or the assembler-optimised implementations? They're all in that file.

Answer (score 1):

The AES implementation is in [rijndael.cpp](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/c5/rijndael.cpp). You asked for the sbox, add round key and mix operations; they're all in the QUARTER_ROUND macros:

- `QUARTER_ROUND_FE` - the first encryption round
- `QUARTER_ROUND_E` - subsequent encryption rounds
- `QUARTER_ROUND_LE` - the last encryption round

and equivalent decryption macros ending in `D` not `E`. These are defined as

```
#define QUARTER_ROUND(L, T, t, a, b, c, d)  \
    a ^= L(T, 3, byte(t)); t >>= 8;\
    b ^= L(T, 2, byte(t)); t >>= 8;\
    c ^= L(T, 1, byte(t)); t >>= 8;\
    d ^= L(T, 0, t);

#define TL_M(T, i, x) (*(word32 *)((byte *)T + x*8 + (i+3)%4+1))
#define QUARTER_ROUND_E(t, a, b, c, d)      QUARTER_ROUND(TL_M, Te, t, a, b, c, d)
```

where

- `TL_M` is the mixing macro
- `Te` is the encryption S-box
- `t` is a 32-bit portion of the key
- `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are 32-bit portions of the current block

Comment: but my question if this code that used in crypto++ library

Comment: Yes, that link is to the [crytopp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptopp/) project on SourceForge. Why do you specifically need the Crypto++ implementation?

Comment: That is the portable version, though; depending on how you've compiled it and what system it's running on you might really be using one of the assembler implementations further down the file.

Comment: CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
    //
    stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( plaintext.c_str() ), plaintext.length() + 1 );
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();   ____ how this code make the encryption

Comment: That depends what `cbcEncryption` is - it applies that to the stream of data you give it. I assume that `cbcEncryption` is something you've created from `AESEncryption`? That's defined as an alias of `RijndaelEncryption` which is implemented using the code I've posted above.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not easy to find the internal code of AES rounds,